# XPages file upload control renames docx and xlsx files

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

if i try to upload a file with the default XPages file upload control and save the document everything works with images like jpgs or psd but if you try to upload a docx oder xslx file the server renames it like ATT7ASLO.zip. In the download control the name is displayed correct.

Is there any solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You need to add these file types to the web\file identification section in the name and adressbok. Because docx and xlxs is actually zip files with another mime type.

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.se/2009/06/serving-correct-mime-types-for-office.html

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412063